# Gnome-logs cannot read system protocol in 20.04

Tags: gnome, log

I have recently upgraded form 19.10 to 20.04. When I open Gnome-logs there is a red banner with the warning in German "Systemprotokoll konnte nicht gelesen werden" which translates as "System logs cannot be read".

When I look under var/logs I find some folders such as cups and some files such as boot.log are marked with a white cross in a red circle and I can only open them as root.

This has never occurred with other releases, what could the problem be?